# Is there a way to make the bibliography appear a number of times in a document?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, article

I'm currently creating a short document with a number of projects that are being offered by my school. However, each project has roughly 2-3 citations and are unique to each project.

More to the point, at the end of each project I would like to include a small reference section, is this possible?

Luckily the references will all be from the same .bib file but I'm still not sure where to begin.

Comment: Take a look at `biblatex` documentation, §3.7.4, *Bibliography sections*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use biblatex, you can use the `refsection` environment to specify a section of the text which has its own independent bibliography, like this:

```
[...]
\begin{refsection} % first project
% some text with citations
\printbibliography % references for the first project
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection} % second project
% another text with citations
\printbibliography % references for the second project
\end{refsection}
[...]
```

For more details, see the [biblatex documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), section 3.7.4 ("Bibliography Sections").